# create a Pandas DataFrame from a series of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas series of list

```
0 ['2018-3-13', '16:00']
1 ['2018-3-13', '16:01']
2 ['2018-3-13', '16:02']
3 ['2018-3-13', '16:03']
.
.
.
```

And I want to create DataFrame as

```
0 '2018-3-13' '16:00'
1 '2018-3-13' '16:01'
2 '2018-3-13' '16:02'
3 '2018-3-13' '16:03'
...
```

So anyone could provide a innovative idea?

Quite thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way is to extract the NumPy array representation and use [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html). You can then feed into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([['2018-3-13', '16:00'], ['2018-3-13', '16:01'],
               ['2018-3-13', '16:02'], ['2018-3-13', '16:03']])

df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), columns=['date', 'time'])

print(df)

        date   time
0  2018-3-13  16:00
1  2018-3-13  16:01
2  2018-3-13  16:02
3  2018-3-13  16:03
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply` and `pd.Series` such as:

```
# with jpp data
s = pd.Series([['2018-3-13', '16:00'], ['2018-3-13', '16:01'],
               ['2018-3-13', '16:02'], ['2018-3-13', '16:03']])
# then you use apply and rename
df = s.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'date',1:'time'})
```

just another method